# Kernel modules and Pi board versions

Tags: pi-zero-w, modules, i2s

I have a Raspbian image (4.9.59-v7) into which I am loading a kernel module that I have built myself since it is not in the default image (for an ICS43432 MEMS I2S microphone).

I have this working without issue on a Raspberry Pi B+; my module `snd_soc_ics43432` is listed as present after boot by `lsmod` and I know it runs correctly 'cos I can record stuff.  I've also modified the `boot` and `rootfs` partitions on this SD card to run read-only in preparation for using it in an environment where I have little control over the power supply. Hence the disk image is a **fixed** thing.

I have now plugged the same SD card into a Pi Zero W and it works there EXCEPT that it is unable to load the ICS43432 module.  During boot it says:

`systemd-modules-load[92]: Failed to find module 'snd-soc-ics43432'`

...and if I use `insmod` to manually insert the module I get:

`ERROR: could not insert module sound/soc/codecs/snd-soc-ics43432.ko: Invalid module format`

Running `sudo modinfo` on this module file returns:

`vermagic: 4.9.59-v7+ SMP mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8`

...which looks correct to me, and indeed it has to be since the goldarned SD card is read-only.

So what gives? Is there a difference between the Broadcom chips on the Pi Zero W versus the Pi B+ that would cause this?  Or is it some sort of timing race condition?  Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: The time to upgrade to Raspbian Buster 2019-09-26 is **NOW**. Your system is too far back-level to be secure and your OS distro is most likely end-of-life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I think I've answered my own question.  My Pi B+ is ARM V7:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 57.60
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
vCPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 57.60
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 57.60
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 57.60
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a01041
Serial          : 00000000a8477217
```

...while my Pi Zero W is ARM V6:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 997.08
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : 9000c1
Serial          : 00000000e39dea37
```

I guess I will have to recompile that kernel module in order to swap between boards.

Comment: Your RPiB+ is a 3B+ the B+ launched in 2014 has the same processor as the zero.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.